# Precaching network responses using `Isolates` with Dio and Hive

Tags: flutter, dart, caching, flutter-hive, dart-isolates

I just want to precache some endpoint calls at the beginning of the app to load faster some request since the backend service is really slow.

I've tried using Isolates for this but seems like Hive Cache doesn't support that, so even if I try to request on another Isolate it will ended up taking the same time **(20-30 seconds)** the same request when I'm trying to pull for the second time, where it should cache it.

Since I read it wasn't supported yet, and I personally think is critical, I moved to just call the endpoints meanwhile the app is loading a bunch of stuff in the main thread. I dont want to delay any more the app so I just want to preload 5 endpoints, so that the next time I'm requesting again it can perform faster.

**1. First Approach**, with Isolates

I'm calling this inside a function

```
 final requestsToPrecache = events
     .map((entityId) =>
         _dataRepository.getEventTable(entityId: entityId))
     .toList();

  compute(precacheFutureOperations, requestsToPrecache);
```

Then this function is the one I'm passing thru Isolates

```
void precacheFutureOperations(List<Future> functions) {
  Future.wait(functions);
}
```

**2. Second Approach**, just not calling await on the Network Request to trigger the request and cache them, so I dont need to wait for the response since I just want to execute it and keep it in cache before it is used, so I just call b

```
precacheFutureOperations(requestsToPrecache);
```

All of this trigger the endpoints I want to precache succesfully, I am monitoring that using proxyman. The weird part is that it doesnt cache them this way. Only after I call the request normally for the Detail Screen, is that it actually caches as expected if I tried to re-enter the screen.

What can I do to precache multiple request at the beginning of the app

Comment: where is the question

Comment: I have no idea where the Hive Cache comes in, or why it is a problem you would have to use `await`. Your question has no actual question, either. Can you edit that in please?

Comment: @Gwhyyy question had been updated, thank you.

Comment: @nvoigt Im  using Hive as Cache since the beginning working effectively, but Im not able to pre-cache a list of requests I jus want to load so the first time I enter the Screen, the request should be cache and the data should show also fast, not taking 24 seconds.

Comment: As I suggested to you in slack, I believe the best solution is a RiverPod FutureProvider.family (or its modern equivalent) which can be triggered in parallel quickly, cached upon receipt, and then as needed, individual providers can be awaited slightly if needed.